# Trying to copy the contents of a schema to another schema

Tags: t-sql

i have found this bit of code which transfers the data but due to the While Exsists if I change TRANSFER to INTO it will run for ever.   How can i change this to iterate through the code schema just the once.

```sql
declare @sql varchar(8000), @table varchar(1000), @oldschema varchar(1000), @newschema   varchar(1000)

  set @oldschema = 'Test'
  set @newschema = 'Live'

 While EXISTS( select * from sys.tables where schema_name(schema_id) = @oldschema)

  begin
      select @table = name from sys.tables 
      where object_id in(select min(object_id) from sys.tables where  schema_name(schema_id)  = @oldschema)

    set @sql = 'alter schema [' + @newschema + '] TRANSFER [' + @oldschema + '].[' + @table + ']'

   exec(@sql)
   
 end
```

I tried adding in a variable to count up and changing While exsists to While variable <1 but the variable didnt seam to increment.

```sql
declare @sql varchar(8000), @table varchar(1000), @oldschema varchar(1000), @newschema   varchar(1000), @cs INT =0

  set @oldschema = 'Live'
  set @newschema = 'Test'
  

  While @cs<1 (select * from sys.tables where schema_name(schema_id) = @oldschema)

  begin
    Set @cs = @cs+1
    
      select @table = name from sys.tables 
      where object_id in(select min(object_id) from sys.tables where  schema_name(schema_id)  = @oldschema)

    set @sql = 'alter schema [' + @newschema + '] INTO [' + @oldschema + '].[' + @table + ']'
 
   exec(@sql)
   
 end
```

Comment: FYI, syntax like `'...[' + @newschema + ']...'` does *not* make for injection safe code.

Comment: `ALTER SCHEMA INTO` is not valid TSQL. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: The only statement in the `while` loop is `(select ...)`. The `begin`/`end` block after that is not part of the loop. Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: `While @cs<1 (select * from sys.tables where schema_name(schema_id) = @oldschema)` is the same as `While @cs<1 begin (select * from sys.tables where schema_name(schema_id) = @oldschema); end;` so the loop is doing nothing. I suspect you wanted `While exists (select 1 from sys.tables where schema_name(schema_id) = @oldschema) begin ...` also `select @table = name from sys.tables ...` should be `select top (1) @table = name from sys.tables ...`